# How to enable smart invert for status bar in iPhone X?

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

This is my code.

In the viewWillAppear method, I set:

```
self.view.enableSmartInvert()

extension UIView {
    @objc(enableSmartInvert)
    public func enableSmartInvert() {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.accessibilityIgnoresInvertColors = true
        }
    }
}
```

I could enable Smart Invert in other devices (iPhone 7, 7Plus...) okay. But in iPhone X (XS, XS Max, XR), it's not okay. It's still the same as Classic Invert with StatusBar.

Also, I tried to get StatusBar View. But it's still not okay.

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.enableSmartInvert()

extension UIApplication {
    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }
}
```

Do you any ideas about this case?

Comment: I tried to do the below code

UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.superview?.enableSmartInvert()

It's okay. But I don't know the reason why. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: You keep saying "it's okay", "it's not okay". What does that even _mean_?

Comment: "It's okay" which means: "Status Bar able to enable Smart Invert". "It's not okay" which means:  "Status Bar unable to enable Smart Invert".